# Using C# datetime in SQL where statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Below is my code(C#), however nothing is displayed.

The problem seems to be with the @lastlogged parameter as if I hardcode its value are returned, the value lastlogged has already been converted using Convert.ToDateTime("2012-07-17 15:18:14.993").

**Update** Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@lastlogged".

```
string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM View_AllJobDetails WHERE UpdatedDateStaff >= @lastlogged";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastlogged", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters["@lastlogged"].Value = lastlogged;
```

Comment: Try setting the size of the parameter... `SqlDbType.DataTime, 8);`

Comment: Is the time element stopping the results? It isn't just the date that is checked. Also, `AddWithValue` is preferred: `AddWithValue("@lastlogged", lastlogged);` it can infer that it is a `DateTime`.

Comment: what is datatype of UpdatedDateStaff ?

Comment: UpdatedDateStaff is set as datetime in sqlserver 2008

Comment: You can debug by adding the parameter to the results:  `sqlStr = "SELECT @lastlogged, * FROM View_AllJobDetails";`

Comment: using addwithvalue is no different to what the OP has done. AddWithValue was added to remove an ambigutity with the add method. I assume lastlogged is a DateTime & not a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you embed the lastlogged value itself into sqlStr -

```
string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM View_AllJobDetails WHERE UpdatedDateStaff >= " + string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}",lastlogged);
```

Another approach could be creating a stored procedure in database and add this parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed that sometimes parameters do have problems with dates.  However, it can implicitly convert a string to a date.  Therefore, try:

```
AddWithValue("@lastlogged", lastlogged.ToString)
```